# select statement to output values second table if field from first and second match

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not the greatest SQL guy in the world and this problem has been driving me crazy for about a week now.

I have 3 tables.  The first is an attributes table with the following data:

```
attr_group_table
attr_id   group    price  prefix   id
     4      2       20.00   +      5000
     1      2       30.00   +      5000

attr_table
attr_id   id    value_id   price   prefix
     1    5000        2     10.00    -
     4    5000        3     10.00    +
    13    5000        9     50.00    +

name_table
     id   name
     2    widget1
     3    widget2
     9    widget3
```

So basically, I need all the all the items from the attr_table that match the ID of 5000.  HOWEVER, if those items exist in the attr_group_table with group=2 then use the price and prefix from the attr_group_table.  Then just suck the names about of the name table.  The only data I need returned is the attr_id, name, price, and prefix.

I've been messing around with joins, unions, if's and just can't get the data I want.  Any help/suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use function [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
SELECT 
  attr_table.attr_id, attr_table.id, attr_table.value_id, 
  COALESCE(attr_group_table.prefix, attr_table.prefix) prefix, 
  COALESCE(attr_group_table.price, attr_table.price) price,
  name_table.name
FROM attr_table 
  LEFT JOIN attr_group_table ON attr_table.attr_id=attr_group_table.attr_id
  LEFT JOIN name_table ON attr_table.value_id=name_table.id
```

It will return the first non-null value of its arguments.

Comment: That worked great once I realized I had neglected to mention another condition that needed to be filled.  I had to add a subquery and it then worked great.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select attr_table.attr_id,name,attr_group_table.price, attr_group_table.prefix
From attr_table join attr_group_table
On attr_table.attr_id = attr_group_table.attr_id
join name_table on name._table.id = attr_table.attr_id
Where attr_table.attr_id = 5000 and group = 2
Union
Select attr_table.attr_id,name,attr_table.price, attr_table.prefix
From attr_table join attr_group_table
On attr_table.attr_id = attr_group_table.attr_id
join name_table on name_table.id = attr_table.attr_id
Where attr_table.attr_id = 5000 and group <> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  attr_table.attr_id,
  name_table.name,
  case when attr_group_table.group=2
       then attr_group_table.price
       else attr_table.price end as price,
  case when attr_group_table.group=2
       then attr_group_table.prefix
       else attr_table.prefix end as prefix
FROM
  attr_table left join attr_group_table
  on attr.table.attr_id = attr_group_table.attr_id
  left join name_table on attr_table.attr_id = name_table.id
WHERE
  attr_table.id = 5000
```